# javascript string equal

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a very strange jquery problem:

```
if(response==="success") {
    alert("I am here");
    $('#uploadfile').html('<img src="./uploads/'+file+'" alt="" /><br />'+file);
}
else {
    $('#uploadfile').html(response);
    //$('#attached1').val("error");
}
```

In this code, if response equal `success`, the `uploadfile` element will display "sucess". The `alert("I am here")` will not show.

I don't know why? what's the error in above code.

Comment: You either have an error in your code or `response` is not actually `"success"`.  I'd suggest you set a breakpoint or `console.log(response)` and examine exactly what the `response` value is.

Comment: Why do you say this is an jQuery problem?

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
if($.trim(response) === "success"){
  ......
```

Comment: Hi Sudhir. Your answer is useful. I solved the problem by your way. Thanks very much. It's not a guess, this is a real problem from my code.

Comment: Glad you solved it... :)

Answer (score 0):

May be your browser blocks the alert? Check if there is some indication saying like "alerts are blocked from this page".

This happens when we test pages with lots of alerts in it. Certain browsers stop showing alerts if they think page is creating too many of them.

Try to use console.log("Message...") instead.